# Modifying Venn diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

Could you help me finish this diagram with the same exact combination of colors and all the jazz?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 

\usepackage{verbatim}


\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{scope}[blend group = soft light]
    \fill[red!30!white]   ( 90:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[green!30!white] (210:1.2) circle (2);
    \fill[blue!30!white]  (330:1.2) circle (2);
  \end{scope}
  \node at ( 90:2)    {Typography};
  \node at ( 210:2)   {Design};
  \node at ( 330:2)   {Coding};
  \node [font=\Large] {\LaTeX};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many things are straightforward but I am not at all good at typing in texts from screen shots. So I added bla bla instead...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds}
\definecolor{delan1}{RGB}{160,160,207}
\definecolor{delan2}{RGB}{221,221,255}  
\definecolor{delan3}{RGB}{248,159,207}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,nodes={align=center}]
  \begin{scope}[blend group=soft light]
    \fill[delan3]   (0,0) coordinate(C3) circle[radius=3cm];
    \fill[delan1]   (115:3.5) coordinate(C1) circle[radius=2.5cm];
    \fill[delan2]   (155:3.5) coordinate(C2) circle[radius=2.5cm];
  \end{scope}
  \node[circle,fill=white,fill opacity=0.4,text opacity=1,inner sep=1em] 
    at (1,1) {Blabla\\ blabla blabla\\ blabla blabla\\ blabla };
  \node[circle,fill=white,fill opacity=0.4,text opacity=1,inner sep=1em] 
    at (-1,-1) {Blabla\\ blabla blabla\\ blabla blabla\\ blabla };
  \begin{scope}[node font=\bfseries]
  \path (C1)node[above=1cm]{Content--based}
      (C2) node[left]{Demographic-\\ based}
      ($($(C1)!0.5!(C2)$)!0.3!(C3)$) node{Hybrid}
      (-20:3) node[anchor=south east]{Collaborotive};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[text=gray]
  \path 
      ($($(C1)!0.5!(C2)$)+(135:1)$) node{Hybrid}
      ($($(C1)!0.5!(C3)$)+(45:1)$) node{Hybrid}
      ($($(C2)!0.5!(C3)$)+(-135:1)$) node{Hybrid};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, there is a mistake for the name of a set: "Collaborotive" :-). Best regards.

Comment: @Sebastiano Grazie! You are right. As I say, "I am not at all good at typing in texts from screen shots"... ;-)

Comment: I'm glady to help you or for other eventual very simple suggestions as this. :-)